# Image Index Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, indexing

I want to go step by step through a image index.

What i got so far is that

```
availableImgs = [
    <?php foreach ($photos as $photo):?>
    { desc : '', src : '<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $photo, $size ); ?>', srcset : '<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $photo, 'large' ); ?>' , sizes : '<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_sizes( $photo, 'large' ); ?>' },
    <?php endforeach;?>
    ]

    function addSomeImages(limit) {
        for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        var imgIdx = availableImgs.length;
        $('#endless-gallery').append('<a data-lc-href="' + availableImgs[imgIdx].src + ', ' + availableImgs[imgIdx].srcset + '" data-rel="lightcase:gallery-<?php echo $number; ?>">' +
            '<img src="' + availableImgs[imgIdx].src + '" srcset="' + availableImgs[imgIdx].srcset + '" srcset="' + availableImgs[imgIdx].sizes + '" />' +
            '</a>');
    }
    $('#endless-gallery').justifiedGallery('norewind');
}

addSomeImages(20);
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        addSomeImages(10);
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

I got no this error 'Cannot read property 'src' of undefined'. 
As I write i want to go step by step through the index and load ieach image in the order the are in the index.

Comment: didn't you forget to declare availableImgs with `var availableImgs`?

Comment: no, when i `console.log( availableImgs.length);` i got the right number back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var imgIdx = availableImgs.length;` will give you the number of items in the array (for example 10).

However the array is zero indexed, so if it's a 10 item array the last item is `availableImgs[9]`, not `availableImgs[10]`. `availableImgs[10]` doesn't exist.

Also I think you should be using `availableImgs[i]` inside the for loop, as you are setting `imgIdx` to the length of the array with every iteration, so you'll be looking at the same array index with each iteration of the for loop?

This might work better:

```
function addSomeImages(limit) {
    for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        $('#endless-gallery').append('<a data-lc-href="' + availableImgs[i].src + ', ' + availableImgs[i].srcset + '" data-rel="lightcase:gallery-<?php echo $number; ?>">' +
        '<img src="' + availableImgs[i].src + '" srcset="' + availableImgs[i].srcset + '" srcset="' + availableImgs[i].sizes + '" />' +
        '</a>');
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

To add a "start from image number ?" option as per comments, one option would be to pass the starting node value through with the limit, something like:

To get the first 20 results:

```
addSomeImages(20,0);
```

To get the second 20 results:

```
addSomeImages(20,20);
```

But this might not be that efficient... What might be better would be to update some global variable with the last value of `i` after the loop is finished, then use this as the next value of `i`, next time the function is run:

```
globalCounterForI = 0;

function addSomeImages(limit) {
    for (var i = globalCounterForI; i < limit + globalCounterForI; i++) {
        $('#endless-gallery').append('<a data-lc-href="' + availableImgs[i].src + ', ' + availableImgs[i].srcset + '" data-rel="lightcase:gallery-<?php echo $number; ?>">' +
        '<img src="' + availableImgs[i].src + '" srcset="' + availableImgs[i].srcset + '" srcset="' + availableImgs[i].sizes + '" />' +
        '</a>');
    }
    globalCounterForI = ++i;
}
```

Comment: Whit console.log( availableImgs.length); i got 58 items back.
When i use your code, i see all images and it append everytime i reach the end of the page the 58 images again.
There for i got 'addSomeImages(20);
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   addSomeImages(10);
  }
 });'
But i need to store wich are loaded and wich are left.

Comment: Sorry can edit my comment.
`addSomeImages(20);
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   addSomeImages(10);
  }
 });`

Comment: yes, sorry you're right, I've amended my answer `for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {` is right, as you had it initially, but the inside of the for loop should stay as my answer for the right output? Let me know if that works

Comment: Thanks for the change. But the problem is now that addSomeImage starts everytime again with the first object. What i need ist First 1-20, second 21-41 and so on.

Comment: ok, so you could call this like an sql limit param, so `addSomeImages(20,0)` and `addSomeImages(20,20)` add an extra attribute in the function to pick up on the 0 and 20, and "start" from that value (i.e. `var i = 20` in the second example)

Comment: Yeah exactly, the problem is this part `for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {, `it set it everytime back to 0 but should keep the last index number and continue there.

Comment: Yes, I've added an alternate solution, hope it points you in the right direction!

Comment: I try your code. It only add's 20 and after that it stopps.

Comment: what happens when you call `addSomeImages(20);` again, does it add none, the same 20, or a different 20?

Comment: I try also console.log to look whats happen.
`function addSomeImages(limit) {
   console.log(globalCounterForI);
   for (var i = globalCounterForI; i < limit; i++) {...`
At page load i got 0 back and after downscroll 20.

Comment: you'll need to make sure the scope of the function can see the variable, I can't see the rest of your code, but you'll need to declare the counter with var so it's in the global scope, and then make sure you can see it in the function

Comment: When i add `addSomeImages(20);
 addSomeImages(20);` it only loads 20 images.

Comment: I try to change value at the beginning of the code to from `globalCounterForI = 0;` to `globalCounterForI = 20; `after that no images are shown.

Comment: http://codepen.io/stutippett/pen/yVwQqq this seems to be working for me, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, this is to do with scope, so I've moved the counter to the global object, and also updated the for statement to increment i to the value of limit + counter: http://codepen.io/stutippett/pen/GNewbm. Let me know if this is the expected output